# Нужны ли запятые после "как-то" и "наконец"?

Tags: пунктуация

1. Как-то, сидя в компании приютившей меня семьи, решил
   похвастаться знанием местного языка, заявив: «Mi tranguman», – что в
   переводе означает «я нищий».
2. Наконец, объявили посадку.

Answer (score 1):

1. Э-э... "Компания семьи" выглядит не очень. Два деепричастия в одной фразе – тоже. Запятая, я бы сказал, факультативна.
2. Запятая не ставится.

Comment: Согласен, насчет "компании", не заметил. Пусть будет "в компании приютивших меня людей".

Comment: Не вижу большого греха, чтобы сидеть в компании семьи. "Семья" понимается как "члены семьи"Прием обычный (метатеза, что ли?). Если вам важно подчеркнуть родственные отношения между вашими домохозяевами, можно и оставить.